# Php code to restart varnish server

Tags: php, varnish

Is there any direct php script to restart Varnish server ?

I don't want to open terminal again n again in order to restart varnish server using shell command.

Please help.

Comment: You mean [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)?

Comment: Here is the [varnish library for PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.varnish.php), you could start there.

Comment: Do you actually want to restart it, or more simply flush the cache, reload the config or something like that?